# firebase slow to establish connection to database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a web app that is using Google Firebase authentication and recently I've noticed that when you background the app on an Android device and then come back to the application it takes a very long time to re-establish a web socket connection to the database.

I enabled logging and this is what occurred.  As you can see from the timings on the logging it took nearly 5 minutes to re-connect - why?

```
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:26:54.376Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: from server: {"r":80,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}} 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:32:34.296Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 Websocket connection was disconnected. 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:32:34.297Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 WebSocket is closing itself 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:32:34.298Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Realtime connection lost. 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:32:34.300Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Closing realtime connection. 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:32:34.300Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Shutting down all connections 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:32:34.302Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: data client disconnected 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:32:34.304Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Window isn't visible.  Delaying reconnect. 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:32:34.305Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Trying to reconnect in 297779.38668296754ms 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:32:34.309Z]  @firebase/database: 0: onDisconnectEvents 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:32:36.069Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Listen called for /NEWLADDER/2020 default 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:37:32.088Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Making a connection attempt 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:37:32.096Z]  @firebase/database: getToken() completed. Creating connection. 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:37:32.099Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Connection created 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:37:32.105Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 Websocket connecting to ********
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:37:32.764Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 Websocket connected. 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:37:32.767Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Realtime connection established. 
logger.ts:80 [2020-07-11T10:37:32.768Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: connection ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase client tries to automatically reconnect with exponential back-off. It's hard to say why this takes 5 minutes in your case, but given the above, it makes sense that the longer your app was backgrounded, the longer it may take to reconnect.

If this is a common problem, I recommend explicitly disconnecting and reconnecting the client when the app becomes foregrounded again. So:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
```

Comment: Hi Frank, is this part of the JavaScript SDK? My app is a PWA.

Comment: It appears to have solved the timing issue with it now occurring fairly instantly when a request is made.

Comment: The log does not show Firebase connection attempts for me, just when the connection status has changed. After turning off mobile data on my test device I was hoping the log would show the connection attempts. Is there anywhere that gives the specifics of the exponential back-off strategy Firebase apparently uses? I use a home grown exponential back-off strategy for ad download attempts and would like to compare it.

Comment: Onc eyou [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) you should see this logs about the SDKs connection attemps in your logcat output.